# Conditions for a topological group to be a Lie group

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, topological-groups

In flipping through the Springer lecture notes on Serre's 1964 'Lie Algebras and Lie Groups' lectures at Harvard, I found this pair of suprising results (page 157):

Let $G$ be a locally compact group. Then

> 1. (Gleason-Montgomery-Zippin-Yamabe) G is a real Lie group iff it does not contain arbitrarily small subgroups (i.e., there exists a neighbourhood of the identity containing no nontrivial subgroup).
> 2. (Lazard) G is a $p$-adic Lie group iff it contains an open subgroup $U$ such that $U$ is a finitely generated pro-$p$-group with $[U,U] \subset U^{p^2}$.

Are there further results that tell us when $G$ is a Lie group over $K$, $K = \mathbb{C}$ or $[K: \mathbb{Q}_p] < \infty$?

Comment: Cross-listed on math.se: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442793/conditions-for-a-topological-group-to-be-a-lie-group

Comment: You also might wanna have a look at this amazing breakthrough http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.2324

Comment: For quadratic $K/\mathbf{Q}_p$ with nontrivial automorphism $z\mapsto z'$, $a\in K^{\times}$ not Galois-invariant mod squares, and odd $m\ge 3$, let $q=ax_1^2+x_2^2+\dots+x_{2m}^2$ and $q'=a'x_1^2+x_2^2+\dots+x_{2m}^2$. The ratio of discriminants is nontrivial mod squares, so $q$ and $q'$ are not homothetic, so SO$(q)$ and SO$(q')$ are not isomorphic as algebraic $K$-groups, so also for their *adjoint* quotients since $m$ is odd. So by Zariski closure with analytic and algebraic Ad$_G$, SO$(q)(K)$ and SO$(q')(K)$ are not isomorphic $K$-analytically, but they are isomorphic topologically!

Comment: The point of the previous comment is that in general the $K$-analytic structure on a $K$-analytic Lie group can fail to be determined by the underlying $p$-adic Lie group (or equivalently the underlying topological group) when $K \ne \mathbf{Q}_p$. So asking for a characterization of the existence of a $K$-analytic structure in terms of the underlying topological group may be rather delicate matter.

Answer (score 6):

Every locally compact and locally contractible topological group is a Lie group
(Hofmann-Neeb arXiv:math/0609684).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However - although it is indeed cool and in the same vein as the result that initially excited me - this is clearly not an answer to the question I posed; I asked for similar conditions conditions to those above for Lie groups over $\mathbb{C}$ and extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: I thought the original post asked for "further results that tell us when G is a Lie group".

Answer (score 3):

I like the following theorem of Gleason and Palais (http://vmm.math.uci.edu/PalaisPapers/OnAClassOfTransformGrps%28Gleason%29.pdf): Let $G$ be a locally arcwise connected topological group in which some neighborhood of the identity admits a continuous one-to-one map into a finite dimensional metric space. Then $G$ is a (real) Lie group.

This result follows from a criterion they prove in the same paper which says that a locally arcwise connected topological group is a Lie group provided that its compact metrizable subspaces are of bounded dimension. As they put it, "the criterion is remarkable in that local compactness is not one of the assumptions."

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However - although it is indeed cool and in the same vein as the result that initially excited me - this is clearly not an answer to the question I posed; I asked for similar conditions conditions to those above for Lie groups over $\mathbb{C}$ and extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$.